# How to remove a constraint from entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I generated a EF diagram from a database, but I decided instead of designing the database and generating the edmx, I wanted to design the diagram and generate a database from it.

However, there are still constraints from when I generated the diagram from the database that I can't seem to remove.  One constraint is for a column which no longer exists so the .edmx throws an error.

Is there any way for me to remove this constraint? I do not want to remove it from the database and update from the database because I have made many changes on the diagram and do not want to have to redo them again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .edmx file is just an XML file under the covers.  If worse comes to worst, you can always edit it directly in a text editor if you are careful.  Look for Associations and AssociationSets that match the constraint you are interested in and remove those tags.  Then save the file and reopen in Visual Studio.  Note that if you do this, I would recommend making a backup of the file first, in case you make a mistake somewhere, then you can revert back.

Comment: Although I feel like I shouldn't have had to do this, editing the .edmx file's xml and removing the constraint worked perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once the column is deleted from the designer, try **Clean Solution** and then **Rebuild Solution**. You should be able to delete the constraint at that point.

Comment: Where do I go to delete it? I can only find the constraint under the Model Browser, and right clicking the one I want to get rid of doesn't have delete as an option.

Comment: From the **Model Browser**, right-click on the constraint and choose **Show in Diagram**. That should bring you to the constraint in the diagram, where you can right-click to delete.

Comment: I don't have Show In Diagram as an option. I only have Validate, Update Model from Database, Generate Database from Model, Add Code Generation Item, and Properties. Screenshot here, http://i.imgur.com/ME2ZZSc.png   Thank you for trying to help me figure this one out.

Comment: Are you right-clicking on the constraint? Or on the Associations category (I can't see images; they are blocked by my ISP.)

Comment: On constraints, it did not exist under associations. I was able to fix it by editing the files XML as Brian Rogers suggested.